# What is the behavior of the Granular Permission Service (GPS) null-check on a Multipass attribute?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

One quick question regarding the Granular Permission Service (GPS) null-check change that is being rolled out. I’m assuming if a column does have null values and it’s used in a policy checking whether the column matches a MP attribute, for example, the policy would be false where there are null values - is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is handled by the query implementations.